# Convert AsyncTask to RxAndroid

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java, rx-android

I have the following method to post response to UI using otto  and `AsyncTask`.

```
private static void onGetLatestStoryCollectionSuccess(final StoryCollection storyCollection, final Bus bus) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            bus.post(new LatestStoryCollectionResponse(storyCollection));
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

I need help to convert this `AsyncTask` to `RxJava` using **RxAndroid library**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use .create() but use .defer()

```
Observable<File> observable = Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<File>>() {
  @Override public Observable<File> call() {

    File file = downloadFile();

    return Observable.just(file);
  }
});
```

to know more details see https://speakerdeck.com/dlew/common-rxjava-mistakes

Comment: This seems a little awkward to me. It's creating an Observable that outputs the already downloaded file, which by deferring the creation happens to be executed in the background. I believe Observable.fromCallable would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 11):

This is an example for a file download task using RxJava

```
Observable<File> downloadFileObservable() {
    return Observable.create(new OnSubscribeFunc<File>() {
        @Override
        public Subscription onSubscribe(Observer<? super File> fileObserver) {
            try {
                byte[] fileContent = downloadFile();
                File file = writeToFile(fileContent);
                fileObserver.onNext(file);
                fileObserver.onCompleted();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                fileObserver.onError(e);
            }
            return Subscriptions.empty();
        }
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
downloadFileObservable()
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(observer); // you can post your event to Otto here
```

This would download the file on a new thread and notify you on the main thread.

`OnSubscribeFunc` was deprecated. Code updated to use `OnSubscribe` insted. For more info see [issue 802 on Github.](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/802)

[Code from here.](https://mttkay.github.io/blog/2013/08/25/functional-reactive-programming-on-android-with-rxjava/)

Comment: I can't use this code because: "error: cannot find symbol class OnSubscribeFunc"  and in my gradle I have compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'  and compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'

Comment: @JachumbelechaoUntoMantekilla `OnSubscribeFunc` was deprecated. You can use `OnSubscribe` instead. I have updated my answer and linked to the relevant github issue.

Comment: what about calling unsubscribe?
It is must if the current activity if not finished soon. right?

Comment: onSubscribe is depricated

Answer (score 6):

In your case you can use `fromCallable`. Less code and automatic `onError` emissions.

```
Observable<File> observable = Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<File>() {
        @Override
        public File call() throws Exception {
            File file = downloadFile();
            return file;
        }
    });
```

Using lambdas:

```
Observable<File> observable = Observable.fromCallable(() -> downloadFile());
```